# 32 bit compilation failing on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc, glib

I have an application that requires the use of glib and a 32 bit library supplied by a third party.

When I compile on 32 bit Ubuntu the application builds and runs successfully.
However when I try the same on 64 bit Ubuntu it fails to build because of the following error:

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function ‘_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64’:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:217:53: error: size of array ‘_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0’ is negative
#define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                 ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:214:47: note: in definition of macro ‘G_PASTE_ARGS’
#define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                           ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:217:44: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_PASTE’
#define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                        ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:422:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘G_STATIC_ASSERT’
G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
^
```

Note: I have gcc-multilib and g++-multilib.
I also tried changing the defines inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h` from 8 to 4 with no success.
I also tried installing `libglib2.0-dev:i686` but pkg config in cmake can not find glib. I am also using the appropriate -m32 flags for C, CXX and LD

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with any libraries. The compilation fails before the linking stage. Look at the last error message you quote, it tells exactly what's wrong. Find out how guint64 is defined and what's its size.

Comment: Oh and uf you have changed anything in the installed headers, revert your changes or reinstall.

Comment: Thanks guint64 was typedefed as ```unsigned long``` so I changed it to a ```unsigned long long```.

Comment: Now my issue is that it the linker can not find any of the glib libraries.
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglib-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgio-2.0
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgobject-2.0

Comment: If you change an installed package in any way, you are on your own. I recommennd reinstalling the OS from scratch.

Comment: No idea why glib wouldn't try to use `int64_t` instead of duplicating that.  Seems silly to me.

Answer (score 1):

No idea why glib wouldn't try to use `int64_t` instead of duplicating that.  Seems silly to me.  Maybe they do this on purpose to increase the chance of breaking if you do what you did, and try to compile 32-bit code using a 64-bit glib install.

To compile 32-bit apps, you need 32-bit library object files (`.so`).  They will come with a `glibconfig.h` that has appropriate typedefs for `-m32`.

Installing `libglib2.0-dev:i686` should be the right approach.  I assume you eventually got that sorted out, so the app you're building finds the `-I` include paths and `-L` library paths for it.