# cmake cross platform build gtk

Tags: cmake, gtk3, mingw-w64

I'm very sorry, I am a beginner, I use docker cross platform compilation in Linux environment, and found that it can not be compiled normally. The error message is as follows

minimize https://github.com/jhoneybee/webkitgtk

error info

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/src/main.c.obj
In file included from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/glibconfig.h:9:0,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from /home/root/src/main.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h: In function '_GLIB_CHECKED_ADD_U64':
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:53: error: size of array '_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_0' is negative
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                                     ^
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:229:47: note: in definition of macro 'G_PASTE_ARGS'
 #define G_PASTE_ARGS(identifier1,identifier2) identifier1 ## identifier2
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gmacros.h:232:44: note: in expansion of macro 'G_PASTE'
 #define G_STATIC_ASSERT(expr) typedef char G_PASTE (_GStaticAssertCompileTimeAssertion_, __COUNTER__)[(expr) ? 1 : -1] G_GNUC_UNUSED
                                            ^~~~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:423:3: note: in expansion of macro 'G_STATIC_ASSERT'
   G_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof (unsigned long long) == sizeof (guint64));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gio.h:46:0,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkapplaunchcontext.h:28,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdk.h:32,
                 from /usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h:30,
                 from /home/root/src/main.c:1:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h: At top level:
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'
 uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
 ^~~~~
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: unknown type name 'uid_t'
                                                    uid_t           uid,
                                                    ^~~~~
CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/build.make:63: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/src/main.c.obj' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/src/main.c.obj] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:771: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/raindrop.dir/all' failed
Makefile:116: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
The command '/bin/sh -c make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

This is my cmakelists.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(raindrop VERSION 0.1.0)

file(GLOB SOURCES src/*.c)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GTK3 REQUIRED gtk+-3.0)
pkg_check_modules(WEBKIT2GTK REQUIRED webkit2gtk-4.0)

include_directories(${GTK3_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${WEBKIT2GTK_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTK3_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${WEBKIT2GTK_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${GTK3_CFLAGS_OTHER} ${WEBKIT2GTK_CFLAGS_OTHER})


include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(raindrop ${SOURCES})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)

target_link_libraries(raindrop ${GTK3_LIBRARIES} ${WEBKIT2GTK_LIBRARIES})
```

mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

# cross compilers to use for C, C++ and Fortran
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gfortran)
set(CMAKE_RC_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-windres)

# target environment on the build host system
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

# modify default behavior of FIND_XXX() commands
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
```

dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch

WORKDIR /home/root

COPY ./* ./

RUN echo \
    deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib\
    deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib\
    deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security stretch/updates main\
    deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian-security stretch/updates main\
    deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch-updates main non-free contrib\
    deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch-updates main non-free contrib\
    deb http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch-backports main non-free contrib\
    deb-src http://mirrors.aliyun.com/debian/ stretch-backports main non-free contrib\
    > /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install mingw-w64 cmake build-essential libgtk-3-dev libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev mingw-w64-tools -y
RUN PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/pkgconfig cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=./mingw-w64-x86_64.cmake -B build -S .
RUN make 
CMD sleep 900000
```

Possibly relevant

- [32 bit compilation failing on 64 bit Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37935605/32-bit-compilation-failing-on-64-bit-ubuntu-16-04)
- https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/issues/326

Comment: Please, add your toolchain file and `CMakeLists.txt` into the **question post**. This is how Stack Overflow works: the code should be in the question post, not *linked*. See also [ask].

Comment: so sorry, I'll add immediately.

Comment: According to the output, you use headers from `/usr/include/` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` which are unlikely suitable for **cross-compiling** for Windows. I would suggest you to examine `cmake` output for your project and check, whether it actually notes compilers from your toolchain. Also you may add `VERBOSE=1` option to `make` invocation, and check that exactly yours compilers are used.